# Using an external class in templated method from dll

Tags: c++, templates, dll, entity-component-system

I'm trying to use my game engine into an external project. Everything works fine but I have a problem when I'm trying to create a custom component (That inherits from ABhaviour which is an abstract class representing a component that can be activated/disabled).

**GameObject.h** *(exported with __declspec(dllexport))*

```
// [...]

template <typename Class, typename ... Args>
std::shared_ptr<Class> GameObject::AddComponent(Args... args)
{
    auto newComp = std::make_shared<Class>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    m_components[typeid(*newComp).hash_code()] = newComp;
    m_components[typeid(*newComp).hash_code()]->SetOwner(*this);
    return newComp;
}

// [...]
```

In an other project (That use my game engine), I'm trying to create the custom ABehaviour :

**PlayerController.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <ElkGameEngine/Objects/Components/Behaviours/ABehaviour.h>

class PlayerController :ElkGameEngine::Objects::Components::Behaviours::ABehaviour
{
    PlayerController() = default;
    ~PlayerController() = default;

    void Update();
};
```

After that I add my custom component onto my "Player" GameObject :

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <ElkGameEngine/ElkGameEngine.h>
#include <ElkGameEngine/Objects/AObject.h>
#include <ElkGameEngine/Objects/Components/AComponent.h>

#include "PlayerController.h"

using namespace ElkGameEngine::Objects::Components;
using namespace ElkGameEngine::Objects::Components::Behaviours;

int main()
{
    ElkGameEngine::Managers::EngineManager elkGameEngine;
    elkGameEngine.GetSceneManager()->CreateScene("ElkCraft");

    auto& player = elkGameEngine.GetSceneManager()->CreateEmptyGameObject("Player");
    player.AddComponent<PlayerController>(); /* Here is the problem */

    while (elkGameEngine.IsRunning())
    {
        elkGameEngine.PreUpdate();


        elkGameEngine.PostUpdate();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Visual Studio is unhappy and print me this :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2440   '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'const std::shared_ptr<PlayerController>' to 'std::shared_ptr<ElkGameEngine::Objects::Components::AComponent>' ElkCraft    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\memory  1472    
Error   C2228   left of '.swap' must have class/struct/union    ElkCraft    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\memory  1472
```

Output window :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ElkCraft, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Could Not Find C:\Users\adrie\Desktop\GROUP_2\PFA\ElkCraft\*.dll
1>main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\memory(1472): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'const std::shared_ptr<PlayerController>' to 'std::shared_ptr<ElkGameEngine::Objects::Components::AComponent>'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\memory(1472): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>c:\users\adrie\desktop\group_2\pfa\elkengine\build\elkgameengine\include\elkgameengine\objects\gameobject.h(53): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<ElkGameEngine::Objects::Components::AComponent> &std::shared_ptr<ElkGameEngine::Objects::Components::AComponent>::operator =<PlayerController>(const std::shared_ptr<PlayerController> &) noexcept' being compiled
1>c:\users\adrie\desktop\group_2\pfa\elkengine\build\elkgameengine\include\elkgameengine\objects\gameobject.h(55): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<ElkGameEngine::Objects::Components::AComponent> &std::shared_ptr<ElkGameEngine::Objects::Components::AComponent>::operator =<PlayerController>(const std::shared_ptr<PlayerController> &) noexcept' being compiled
1>c:\users\adrie\desktop\group_2\pfa\elkcraft\sources\main.cpp(18): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<PlayerController> ElkGameEngine::Objects::GameObject::AddComponent<PlayerController,>(void)' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\memory(1472): error C2228: left of '.swap' must have class/struct/union
1>Generating Code...
1>Compiling...
1>PlayerController.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "ElkCraft.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I think that the problem come from the fact that my game engine (Which is a group of DLL) is exporting a templated method (AddComponent and other ones like GetComponent).

- Is it possible to use a templated method from a dll with a class/struct template argument from the project using the dll ?
- Am I doing something wrong ?
- Do I need to specify something on my PlayerController to make it "known/usable" in the AddComponent method ?

Comment: 1. Look at the output window, not the error list window. For C++, this is often a necessity, as there is so much context that is not shown in the error list. 2. Show the declaration of `m_components`. I suspect it is a container which cannot hold an `ABehaviour`

Comment: m_components can definitly hold an ABehaviour. Any components of my engine (Instead of transform) inherits fromt ABehaviour. I can AddComponent<Light>() (Light is an ABehaviour), Camera, ModelRenderer, etc...

Comment: Let's start with some basics. A template is not a function. You cannot export a template from a DLL.

Comment: Additionally, you need to specify that your inheritance is **public**, as in `class PlayerController : public whatever`

Comment: Probably I used wrong words : "templated method" was what I meant. I don't mean to export a template, it makes no sense, I mean exporting a templated method from a DLL. By the way thanks for your last comment (About public thing) that was the solution to my problem, sadly the compiler error wasn't enough detailed

Comment: "templated method" isn't a standard term as of now, it isn't clear what you mean by it. If you mean a trmplate instantiation, you don't need to export any. **The implementation is in the header file**. Client code doesn't need to even see the DLL, all it needs is the header.